# Setting Locale for email template in Magento

Tags: email, magento, locale, magento-1.4, transactional-email

I have a Mageneto 1.4 installation that sends a customised email when orders are put on hold. It all works perfectly, however it will only send English emails. When the orders come in from the English and German store they are still sent the English email.

The holdAction method I'm currently using looks like this:

```
public function holdAction()
{
    if ($order = $this->_initOrder()) {
        try {
            $order->hold()
                ->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Order was successfully put on hold.')
            );
            $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                    ->loadDefault('customer_payment_declined');
            $emailTemplateVariables = array();
            $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order;
            $emailTemplateVariables['customername'] = $order->getCustomerName();
            $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
            $emailTemplate->setSenderName('example.com');
            $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('customerservice@example.com');
            $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Your order – '.$order->getIncrementId());
            $emailTemplate->send($order->getCustomerEmail(),$order->getCustomerName(), $emailTemplateVariables);

        }
        catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Order was not put on hold.'));
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $order->getId()));
    }
}
```

I've tried passing the Locale through in a variety of ways but I'm not having any luck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Different email templates for different languages works well on one of our websites. This also is Magento v.1.4

What we have is two sets of locale:
app/locale/nl_NL/template/email/
app/locale/en_US/template/email/

We also have different locale set for each website scope in:
Configuration -> General -> Locale Options

Comment: Hi marcinsdance. Thanks for the suggestion. We already have locale set up as you suggest so that's not the issue. I played around with a few settings as well but with no luck.